# Magento 2 - remove .html from URL by using .htaccess

Tags: magento2, url, url-rewrite, .htaccess

We have some wrong URLs in our store ending with `.html`. If the user opens such a URL, then the .html should get removed, otherwise the site cant get found.

So I added this rule to my .htaccess file in pub/.htaccess, i also tried the normal .htaccess in the magento root.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

...

############################################
## Remove .html from end of URL

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=302]

</IfModule>
```

But if I enter a URL with .html at the end, then it is still not getting removed.

I want to make it work by using the .htaccess, otherwise I will have to create plenty of URL rewrites by hand.

Comment: Why you not using Magento 2 default configuration for this..?

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I understand actually you want to redirect *.html* page to *without.html* page

You can add following code in .htaccess :
for example :

```
Redirect /specific-page.html /specific-page
```

Comment: Yes, but I dont want to redirect a single page, I want to redirect ALL URLs.

Comment: Try this : `RedirectMatch  (.*)\.html$ http:// example.com$1`